# route helpers not found after overriding engine view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree, rails-engines

whenever I override an engine's view, I get method missing on all the route helpers in the views and also in the helpers from the engine used in the view. How can I make the view to look for the helpers in the engine and not the ones in my application even when it is an overriden view? The engine is spree by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used spree before, but had the same issue with Forem.  Had to use **forem.**the_route_i_want_url and it fixed me right up!  On the flip side (using your normal routes from within the context of the engine) use **main_app.**the_route_i_want_url